# Could someone please translate this code into some mathematical notation?

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution, notation

this [code](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=127bf6d6a4401a7b89566ef30d12fa0ebd90679f&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f70726f626d6c2f707970726f626d6c2f313237626636643661343430316137623839353636656633306431326661306562643930363739662f6e6f7465626f6f6b732f696e74726f2f696e74726f64756374696f6e2e6970796e62&nwo=probml%2Fpyprobml&path=notebooks%2Fintro%2Fintroduction.ipynb&repository_id=65924871&repository_type=Repository#jax) is to generate a dateset

```
def make_1dregression_data(n=21):
    np.random.seed(0)
    xtrain = np.linspace(0.0, 20, n)
    xtest = np.arange(0.0, 20, 0.1)
    sigma2 = 4
    w = np.array([-1.5, 1/9.])
    fun = lambda x: w[0]*x + w[1]*np.square(x)
    ytrain = fun(xtrain) + np.random.normal(0, 1, xtrain.shape) * \
        np.sqrt(sigma2)
    ytest= fun(xtest) + np.random.normal(0, 1, xtest.shape) * \
        np.sqrt(sigma2)
    return xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest

xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest = make_1dregression_data(n=21)
```

Could someone please translate this Python code into some mathematical notation? I've read this code several times and failed to find what distribution it is.

I know it is based on normal distribution although I cannot imagine what this part `w[1]*np.square(x)` is doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although this question relies heavily on Python, the answer does appear to benefit from some statistical reasoning.

This function creates "training" and "test" datasets of points $(x_i,y_i)$ for a regression model

$$y_i = w_0 x_i + w_1 x_i^2 + \varepsilon_i \sigma$$

where $\varepsilon_i$ are independent variables with standard Normal distributions.  The values of the parameters $w_0,$ $w_1,$ and $\sigma$ are hard-coded into the function.  The values of the $x_i$ in each dataset are equally spaced from $0$ to $20$ (although the test set does not include $20$). The test set is hard-coded (as $(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, \ldots, 19.9)$) while the training set size is provided by the caller in the argument `n`.

> The model can also be compactly written by stating that the observations $y_i$ are realizations of independent random variables $Y_i$ having Normal$(w_0x_i+w_1x_i^2, \sigma^2)$ distributions; this frequently is abbreviated as $$Y_i\ {\sim}_{\operatorname{iid}}\ \mathcal{N}(w_0x_i + w_1 x_i^2, \sigma^2).$$

That answers the question about what distribution is involved.

This is the setting for ordinary least squares regression of a response $y$ against "features" or "explanatory variables" $x$ and $x^2.$  Thus, it posits that

> the points $(x_i,y_i)$ deviate from the parabola $y=w_0x + w_1 x^2$ by means of independent random variations in the $y$ coordinates.

That answers the question about what the squared term is doing.